# Omit keys from an object which are present in another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this -

```
const obj = {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3,
   'd': 4,
   'e': 5
}
```

and an array containing keys belonging to the object,

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

I want to return an **object** similar to `obj` but it shouldn't contain the **keys** present in `arr`,
i.e., I want an object which will be

```
const result = {
    'c': 3,
    'e': 5
}
```

How can I achieve this via Javascript?

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), it's easy:

```js
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, _]) => !arr.includes(k)))
```

Without it, it takes a bit more effort:

```js
const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((tot, [k, v]) => {
    if (!arr.includes(k)) {
        tot[k] = v;
    }
    return tot;
}, {})
```

Comment: nice solid answer

Comment: Too bad it has a time complexity of *O(mn)* where *m* is the number of properties in `obj`, and *n* the size of `arr`. So in short: a quadratic time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the object and delete the listed properties:

```js
const obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5};
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd'];

const res = {...obj};
for (let k of arr) delete res[k];

console.log(res);
```

Note that this has a time complexity that is almost linear in terms of the number of properties involved, *O(m+nlogn)* (if `delete` is *O(logn)*), while [Aplet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488105/5459839) would have a quadratic time complexity: *O(mn)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Object#entries` then filter out those entries which are not in the `arr` and using `Object#fromEntries` reconstruct the object:

```js
const obj = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5}, arr = ['a', 'b', 'd'];

const filterObj = (obj, arr) => {
  const dataSet = new Set(arr);
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => !dataSet.has(k)))
};
console.log(filterObj(obj, arr));
```

Another way to filter the object with the supplied keys but without using `Object#fromEntries` is by using `Object#assign`.

We would just `filter` the entries which are not in the given array, then `map` them to *objects* and pass those as parameters to the `Object#assign`:

```js
const obj = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5}, arr = ['a', 'b', 'd'];

const filterObj = (obj, arr) => {
  const keySet = new Set(arr);
  const filteredEntries = Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => !keySet.has(k));
  return Object.assign({}, ...filteredEntries.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})));
}
console.log(filterObj(obj, arr));
```

Comment: Do you introduce the `Set` simply for performance?  My answer just uses `! arr .includes (k)`, which seems to do the same job.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yup! if the given array has a lot of keys, it would take O(n) time to do the lookup.

Comment: Although I'm not going to bother setting up a test for it, I do wonder where the break-even point for the overhead of creating a `Set`.  I wouldn't be surprised to find it's in the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.entries`, you can generate [key, value] pair from object as array.

And based on that, using `Array.reduce`, you can get the result you want.

```js
const obj = {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3,
   'd': 4,
   'e': 5
};

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd'];

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!arr.includes(cur[0])) {
    acc[cur[0]] = cur[1];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` is perhaps not universal yet, but it's common, and it seems simpler than a bespoke `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` solution:

```js
const obj = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5};
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'd'];

const o = Object.keys(obj)
   .reduce((s, a) => (arr.indexOf(a) > -1 ? s : s[a] = obj[a], s), {});
   
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the object and get the rest of it without unwanted keys.

```js
const
    object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
    without = ['a', 'b', 'd'],
    result = without.reduce((r, k) => ({ [k]: _, ...r } = r, r), object);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the object using JavaScript for..in loop. Check property using array indexOf method. If property name is not present in the array then put the property with value in ret variable.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
};

const arr = ["a", "b", "d"];

ret = {};
for (let x in obj) if (arr.indexOf(x) === -1) ret[x] = obj[x];
console.log(ret);
```